# Are all console cables pinned the same?

Tags: console, cable

My workplace is getting new HP A5500 Series switches, and they include a console cable - a DB-9 Female to RJ-45 Male. I know we *talked* about them in college, but never actually seen one. I've heard of them being used in other enterprise-level networking equipment.

I'm wondering now, **are all console cables (like above) pinned out the same?** Can I use this cable on other HP equipment, or even other manufacturer's equipment? Or will it change depending on model or manufacturer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

You'll likely be able to use it on HP and Cisco gear, but there are some situations where the pinout is different or maybe you'll have a device with a DB-9->DB-9 requirement. If in doubt, use the manufacturer's cable.

Answer (score 5):

No. In example if you use a HP/Cisco DB-9 for a APC the UPS will restart direct. (as it will receive a signal on a pin reserved for a command)

For other product most use the standard pinout, but be advised to watch yourselft on critical gear as it can produce un-wanted result.